# How can I create Admin(Manual) order without the Products available in the Website?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, admin-order-create

I need to create manual(Admin) order, without the products present in the website, I mean order create for not available products in website. How to achieve using any custom options?

Comment: Then from where you want to get product? Please explain you requirement in more detail.

Comment: @zus  refer this link    https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/           and when product is not found then u create that product programatically  and store in to db and then create order of that product

Comment: @aman just for invoice purpose, not necessary the products present in the website. In BigCommerce there is option.

Comment: What about a virtual product?  I suggest you to use Virtual product concept.

Comment: @PankajSharma  Virtual product also need to entries right, i need without any products i mean the products not present in the website, even we need to create manual order.

Comment: @zus not a better way but I think it is possible if you create sales order item programmatically and then associate with order programmatically. You may require executing direct SQL queries using adapter.

Comment: @gulshanmaurya okay, can i get some reference for how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a simple product under `Catalog->Manage Products`
2. Choose a generic name for the product like **"Custom Item"** and set some Price *(it does not matter)*
3. In section **"Custom Options"** Add New Option
4. Set **Input Type** to *Text Field* and name it "Name" or "Product Name"
5. Set Price to 0.0, Fixed, empty SKU and **is Required** to *Yes*
6. After saving the product create new Order at `Sales->Orders`
7. Push "**Add Products**" and add newly created product to the order
8. When adding a product you will see a button **"configure"** where you can set the **actual name** of item to order
9. To change the price simply click on checkbox **"Custom Price"**
10. Voila!

> Adding generic order items is dirty. I do not recommend to use this
>   workflow, if you wish clean sales reports

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, you have very good stuff. However may be search some other option, and i +1 for your post..

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your problem and provide further information.

I assume that you mean a 'product not present in website' that it hasn't been created in Magento?  If so, then it is not possible in standard Magento.

However, I am sure it is possible using custom code - all of the details needed for the orders are stored in the order flat tables (specifically sales_flat_order_item) such as the sku, product name, price sold at, etc.

This means that a product can be deleted and functionality such as shipping, credit memo, etc, will remain.

Can you please provide further information and the level of customisation you're willing to do to achieve as it is not a trivial exercise.

If you're saying that a product has been created in Magento but is not visible in the website then it can be done via the order panel - Sales->Orders->Create New Order.

Comment: Okay, Let us give chance to others share their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

@zus: This is not possible out of the box in Magento. I believe non of the eCommerce system will give you an option to create an invoice without having details in it.

Please share the details of BigCommerce so that we can have a look and it will good learning for us as well.

What is your plan or requirements? Simple solution for your problem is to create a product in Magento and hide it for frontend user. You can create as many as order you want to create, make pricing adjustment etc. This will also help in tons of other ways in future. For example in reporting, tally your accounts and many other ways.

Comment: Here are the details: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Creating-a-Manual-Order

Comment: Bigcommerc users know this, how to create order without products. I just want to know it's possible in Magento or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set **Visibility** of products to "Not Visible Individually" if that is what you mean.
2. If your question is about **stock availability**, and you want to force unavailable products into an order, then there are several options starting with enabling backorder up to customization of admin.
3. And finally if you meant **non-existing products**, there is an option to implement custom ajax form into admin order form to create products during order creation process.

Comment: No, you misunderstand, let me explain.  I need to order for not existing products, like just enter name, price, qty in order creation. In Bigcommerce there is option for that, like can i create for this in Magento.

Comment: that is what i mean with option 3. Product need to be created anyways, because in magento database architecture every entity is cross-referenced in each table. As a workaround it is also possible to create an all-around product and write data in its custom options from order creation form.

Comment: Okay, thanks for once again clarify for me, Can i get any reference for create that kind of process.

Comment: ok, no code changes or customization is initially required. only if you want this order items to look different in order confirmation email or elsewhere. it will add a separate answer

Comment: okay, i am waiting.